# Why is enforcing system-reserved reservations in Kubernetes dangerous?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm reading the Kubernetes docs on [Reserve Compute Resources for System Daemons](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/), and it says "Be extra careful while enforcing system-reserved reservation since it can lead to critical system services being CPU starved, OOM killed, or unable to fork on the node."

I've seen this warning in a few places, and I'm having a hard time understanding the practical implication.

Can someone give me a scenario in which enforcing `system-reserved` reservation would lead to system services being starved, etc, that would NOT happen if I did not enforce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have at least a few things running on the host nodes outside of Kubernetes' view. Like systemd, some hardware stuffs, maybe sshd. Minimal OSes like CoreOS definitely have a lot less, but if you're running on a more stock OS image, you need to leave room for all the other gunk that comes with them. Without leaving RAM set aside, the Kubelet will happily use it all up and then when you go to try and SSH in to debug why your node has gotten really slow and unstable, you won't be able to.

Comment: Isn't this a reason to enforce system-reserved reservation, rather than not? From the docs: "system-reserved is meant to capture resource reservation for OS system daemons like sshd, udev, etc." The way I read this, it would ensure that resources are available for things like sshd, etc.

Comment: If you set the system-reserved too low, sshd won't have RAM to operate :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand why it is bad if the system doesn't have the resources needed to operate. I was confused by the phrasing in the k8s docs - I interpreted this as cautioning that enforcing system-reserved is inherently more dangerous than not doing anything. I don't believe that to be the case, because if it's not enforced at all, system processes can still run out of resources, resulting in the same problem.

Comment: There's two different things, you can do a simple resource reservation which just factors in to the RAM available for the kubelet, or you can actually enforce it via cgroups. Turning on enforcement, if you got the number wrong, can be very bad :)